# Where should a render camera be placed in order to replicate an actual photo?

Tags: photography, maya

I am looking to replicate an actual photo with an Autodesk Maya render. However, every time I attempt a render it seems to be looking a bit down and to the left in relation to the actual photo, e.g.:

[image: test_render]

At the moment I am placing the render camera in Maya centered at the end of the lens of the actual camera simply because I haven't found any resource that tells me otherwise. My guess is that either the render camera needs to be somewhere between the end of the lens and the sensor plane or that my method of determining the rotation of the physical camera is slightly off.

Comment: Are you also adjusting correctly for stuff such as focal length? Unless you know *all* parameters of your camera (and how to enter them into Maya), trial-and-error would be useful – which comes down to taking the actual camera view for granted and adjusting Maya until you got it right.

Comment: 3D questions are no longer in the scope of this site.  I know this also deals a little with photography, but the main issue you're presenting seems to be camera rigging inside Maya.  There is a proposal for a 3D SE [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86368/3d-graphics), so if it's something you'd like to see head over there and commit to it.

Comment: @RadLexus focal length, sensor size, it's a full frame sensor so I don't need to adjust for crop factor...is there anything else major that I'm missing?

Comment: And don't forget about 2d Pan\Zoom ;)

Comment: The camera should be placed at your camera/lense combinations focal plane which is somewhere nearer the center of your camera body. closer to the location on the very base of your lense but you will need to measure this.